# How to schedule a task with Celery that runs after three months and only once

Tags: django, celery

I have created an advertising app in my websilte with django and the Ad model looks like this

```
AdModel(models.Model):

    starting_date = models.DateField()
    expiring_date = models.DateField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My goal is to create a task using Celery to activate (set ad.active = True) and deactivate ads based on their starting and expiring date and since the celery beat is for periodic **recurring** task so it's not going to solve it.

Probably passing the *starting_date* as eta to the task like this will be the solution:

```
#signals.py
@receiver(post_save, sender=AdModel)
def start_task(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ad_activator_task.apply_async( (instance.id), eta=instance.starting_date)
```

If the **instance.starting_date** is three months far from now, is it going to be executed ? i have read that [Celery not usefull for long term future tasks (far future)](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4522) and i'm kinda confused.

*note: im using Redis as broker*

Comment: Why set an `active` field anyway? You can simply calculate if it is active by looking at the `starting_date` and `expiring_date`.

Comment: set active field to control the ad through my custom admin site (activate/deactivate) without looking at the dates

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise *not* to implement this with scheduled tasks. You better do not use an `active` field anyway: whether an ad is active is here determine by the `starting_date` and the `expiring_date`. We can thus model this as:

```
class AdModel(models.Model):
    starting_date = models.DateField()
    expiring_date = models.DateField()
```

We can use annotations to determine if an `AdModel` is active with:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Now

AdModel.objects.annotate(
    active=ExpressionWrapper(
        Q(starting_date__lte=Now(), expring_date__gte=Now()),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)
```

If you need this often, you can make a `Manager` that will automatically annotate `AdModel.objects`:

```
class AdModelManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            active=ExpressionWrapper(
                Q(starting_date__lte=Now(), expring_date__gte=Now()),
                output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        )

class AdModel(models.Model):
    starting_date = models.DateField()
    expiring_date = models.DateField()

    objects = AdModelManager()
```

If you want extra control, you can just add an extra nullable boolean field `force_active` that is set to NULL by default, but you can set it to `True`/`False` to override the expiration mechanism:

```
from django.db.models import Coalesce

class AdModelManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            active=Coalesce('force_activate', ExpressionWrapper(
                Q(starting_date__lte=Now(), expring_date__gte=Now()),
                output_field=BooleanField()
            ))
        )

class AdModel(models.Model):
    starting_date = models.DateField()
    expiring_date = models.DateField()
    force_activate = models.BooleanField(null=True)

    objects = AdModelManager()
```

Comment: i added the 'active' field to control the ad through the admin interface even if it's not in the range of starting and expiring date, and to activate the ad manually in case of task failure.

Comment: @TonyxD: then I would add something as a field `blocked`, or a nullable field `force_active` that can override the annotation. But using scheduled tasks, it looks inelegant, and error-prone. Especially if you then later would aim to make it more scalable.

Comment: I'm using the scheduled tasks to make the activation/deactivation of the ad Automatic when the staring_date or the expiring_date is today, what i'm concerned about is can celery execute the task if it's in the far future

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with inelegant workaround wish is creating a periodic task that runs everyday at midnight to check for ads to activate/deactivate and the task is like so:

```
#tasks.py
@shared_task
def activate_deactivate_ads():
    to_activate = AdModel.objects.filter(date_started=timezone.now().date())
    if to_activate.exists():
        to_activate.update(active=True)

    to_deactivate = AdModel.objects.filter(date_expires=timezone.now().date(), active=True)
    if to_deactivate.exists():
        to_deactivate.update(active=False)
```

and the beat config :

```
#settings.py
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'activate-deactivate-ads': {
   'task': 'tasks.activate_deactivate_ads',
    # Excecute everyday at midnight
   'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=0),
    }
  }
```

any other approachs are welcome